# How to get multiple records from firebase?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase db with data like below:
[image]

I want to pull multiple records based on certain criteria.  I've figured out how to pull a single record based on an ID using the method below:

```
ref := fbDB.NewRef("/Event/123")
event := data.EventData{}
if err := ref.Get(c, &event); err != nil {
   // error handling stuff
}
```

This loads `event` with the data I would expect.  When I try to modify this code to select multiple records with the code below:

```
type EventResults struct {
    Events []data.EventData
}
...
ref := fbDB.NewRef("/Event")
res := EventResults{}
if err := ref.Child("candy").OrderByValue().StartAt(350).Get(c, &res); err != nil {
   //error handling stuff
}
```

`res.Events` is always an empty array (and `err` is nil).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's empty because when retrieving data you need to traverse the database and pass through each node.

In your case you have this:

```
ref.Child("candy");
```

Here `ref` is referencing the node `Event` and under `Event` you have different Ids (`123`, `789`), therefore you need to access these nodes before trying to access node `candy`.

---

If you want to retrieve a list of `candy` that are under `Event`, then you should iterate inside the direct child of node `Event` then you will be able to access node `candy`.

Example:

```
f := firego.New("https://my-firebase-app.firebaseIO.com", nil)
var res map[string]interface{}

ref := fbDB.Ref("/Event")
if err := ref.OrderBy("candy").StartAt(3).Value(&res); err != nil {

}
```

You need to use the `OrderBy` query to be able to retrieve result based on the value of of `candy`. For example, in my code `OrderBy("candy").StartAt(3)`, this query will give you a result where the value of candy starts with 3. `candy :300`

Check the docs:

https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/zabawaba99/firego.v1

Comment: So what I actually want is to get the individual events where the value for candy falls within a certain range.  How do I limit the event records that i'm pulling based on the value of `candy`?  I understand that `ref.Child("candy")` isn't right but i'm not clear on what I should be doing instead

Comment: check my edit in the answer , also I dont know golang, but the code that I wrote should work according to the search that I did about `go`

Comment: Hrrm, I'm not using the firego package but let me see if I can work out how to apply it to the built in library: https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/db

Comment: @AbeMiessler okay if you are using the link above then do `ref.OrderByChild("candy").StartAt(3).Get(&res)`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what Peter posted above but the exact code I ended up using is below:

```
ref := fbDB.NewRef("/Event")
var res map[string]data.EventData

if err := ref.OrderByChild("candy").StartAt(350).Get(c, &res); err != nil {
    //Error handling stuff
}
```